# Mongodb: How can I find the nested group that maximizes the values max/min length and calculate the average?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with trainings (T) that contains an exercises array and I would like find the nested group that maximizes the values max/min length and calculate the average. The collection is such as:

```javascript
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e456e6b33fef4299aa75a7e"),
    "title" : "Training aaa and bbb",
    "exercises" : [{
            "title" : "aaa exercise",
            "goals" : ["aaa"],
            "length" : 10
     },{
            "title" : "bbb exercise",
            "goals" : ["bbb"],
            "length" : 5
     }],
    "createdBy" : "dummy"
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e456e7f33fef4299aa75a7f"),
    "title" : "Training aaa, ccc",
    "exercises" : [{
            "title" : "aaa exercise",
            "goals" : ["aaa"],
            "length" : 5
        },{
            "title" : "aaa exercise",
            "goals" : ["aaa"],
            "length" : 10
        },{
            "title" : "ccc exercise",
            "goals" : ["ccc"],
            "length" : 5
    }],
    "createdBy" : "dummy"
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e49b282e0a271e9f57648ff"),
    "title" : "Training aaa 2",
    "exercises" : [{
            "title" : "aaa",
            "goals" : ["aaa"],
            "length" : 5
    },{
            "title" : "ccc exercise",
            "goals" : ["ccc"],
            "length" : 10
    }],
    "createdBy" : "dummy"
}]
```

I would like finding the min/max/avg by goal and training. With the before values, expected values should fit with:

```javascript
[{
    _id: "aaa"
    min: 5,  // T1: 5  
    max: 15, // T2: 5 + 10
    avg: 10  // T1,T2,T3: (10+15+5)/3 = 10
},{
    _id: "bbb",
    min: 5,  // T1: 5
    max: 5,  // T1: 5
    avg: 5   // T1: 5/1 = 5
},{
    _id: "ccc",
    min: 5,  // T2: 5
    max: 10, // T3: 10
    avg: 5   // T2,T3: (5+10)/2 = 7,5 
}]
```

In this example, aaa was train 10 minutes in the first training, 15 in the second and 5 in the third one. So min=5, max=15, avg: (10+15+5)/3 = 10

I tried the following, but I did not get the expected result although it is close:

```javascript
db.getCollection('trainings').aggregate([
    {$match : {"createdBy" : "dummy" } },
    {$unwind: "$exercises"},
    {$unwind: "$exercises.goals" },
    {$group: {
        _id: "$exercises.goals",
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        lengthAvg: {$avg: "$exercises.length"},
        lengthMin: {$min: "$exercises.length"},
        lengthMax: {$max: "$exercises.length"},
        lengthSum: {$sum: "$exercises.length"}
        }
    }
])
```

I think the issues is with $unwind stage that deconstructs the exercises and group by training is lost. But I am not sure how change it.

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure of your expected results? min 10, max 15, avg 10???

Comment: I think so. Why? Did you found something weird? The idea is calculate min, max and average per goal of all trainings and maximize results.

Comment: [{
    _id: "aaa"
    min: 5,
    max: 15,
    avg: 10
},{
    _id: "bbb",
    min: 5,
    max: 5,
    avg: 5
},{
    _id: "ccc",
    min: 5,
    max: 10,
    avg: 7.5
}]

Comment: @mattPen you are right. I focused only on aaa. I have just corrected it. Thx.

Comment: ok, better understand. Can there be multiple values in your goals array, ie goals:["aaa","ccc"]?

Comment: yes, it can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were touching the solution with your query. The trick is to group first by training to get sum of goals inside each trainning, then group by goals to get needed metrics.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "createdBy": "dummy"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$exercises"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$exercises.goals"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        trainingId: "$_id",
        goal: "$exercises.goals",

      },
      totalPerTraining: {
        $sum: "$exercises.length"
      }
    }
  },
 {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.goal",
      lengthMin: {
        $min: "$totalPerTraining"
      },
      lengthMax: {
        $max: "$totalPerTraining"
      },
      lengthAvg: {
        $avg: "$totalPerTraining"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      lengthSum: {
        $sum: "$totalPerTraining"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nIZRoKJKJ7E)

---EDIT---

*Although the previous aggregation will perfectly work, it can consume a lot of resources by unwinding twice. I highly recommand for this kind of needs to use [map/reduce approach](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/), more efficient in your case.*

```
  map = function () {
    var trainingSums = {};
    this.exercises.forEach(function (exercise) {
      exercise.goals.forEach(function (goal) {
        if (trainingSums[goal] == null) {
          trainingSums[goal] = 0;
        }
        trainingSums[goal] += exercise.length;
      })
    });

    for (property in trainingSums) {
      print(trainingSums);
      emit(property, trainingSums[property]);
    }
  };
  reduce = function (key, values) {
    var reducedValues = {};
    reducedValues.sum = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    reducedValues.min = Math.min(...values);
    reducedValues.max = Math.max(...values);
    reducedValues.avg = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / values.length;
    reducedValues.count = values.length;
    return reducedValues;
  };
  finalize = function (key, reducedValue) {
    var finalValue = {};
    if (!isObject(reducedValue)) {
      finalValue.sum = reducedValue;
      finalValue.min = reducedValue;
      finalValue.max = reducedValue;
      finalValue.avg = reducedValue;
      finalValue.count = 1;
    } else
      finalValue = reducedValue;
    return finalValue;
  };
```

The map function is calculating the sum for each goals in a training, then emit this.

The reduce function is calculating your metrics.

The finalize function is here to define metrics when a goal was found only once in all traings (like your 'ccc' goal in example), because in this case the reduce function will not be applied.

> **For those keys that have multiple values**, MongoDB applies the reduce phase, which collects and condenses the aggregated data.

Comment: `lengthSum: { $sum: "$exercises.length" }` should be replaced by: `lengthSum: { $sum: "$totalPerTraining" }`. Everything else is perfect. Thx!